# SD Card Reader going to sleep

Tags: windows, power-management, sd-card, pci-express

My SD card reader on my new 12th gen Intel HP laptop goes to sleep after 12 or so seconds.  Any action on it after that (that isn't cached) takes 3 seconds.  My wife's computer has the same issue but it lags around 1 full second.

I found this from a while ago and it seems to describe my exact problem.  It's a closed issue though and no resolution.  On the 2nd page it mentions going from D0 to D3.  I have noticed this as well.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-2004-makes-sdxc-card-reader-pause-and/6e1a9481-05c3-4134-b95e-bca550308049?page=1

This is easily testable from command prompt by doing something like `mkdir D:\test-01`, then `mkdir D:\test-02`, etc.  Just sleep 15 seconds between making directories and you'll notice it takes 1 to 3 seconds to complete.

I thought perhaps some HP software was trying to do some power savings so I installed a fresh copy of Win11 by flashing a USB with the Media Creation Tool.  That didn't solve anything.

I have an older Lenovo laptop which I think has a 7th gen Intel processor and it doesn't have this behavior.

I'm wondering if this is normal behavior on these newer Intel laptops for power savings but I haven't been able to find someone else to verify.

I should also note that there is no `Power Management` tab on this device.  Perhaps some USB things have this option but not this card reader as it's PCIe.  The one on my Lenovo is also PCIe but doesn't have this issue.

Comment: is this an internal reader?

Comment: Have you tried an external USB card reader? They're available for $US8 or less. One also makes it easier to read cards on this laptop, where the reader port is inconvenient, and handles µXD cards with an adapter, too.

Comment: Yes it's an internal card reader that is apparently utilizing PCI.

Comment: Yes I've tried an external USB reader and it exhibits no problems.  The internal one would be ideal because when inserted it's flush and not protruding.